# How to call stored procedure in for loop using c#

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, stored-procedures

I want call a stored procedure in a loop, but command time out when use command query, but if use linq then call stored procedure causes a runtime error:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException
>   HResult=0x80131501
>   Message=An error occurred while starting a transaction on the provider connection. See the inner exception for details.
>   Source=EntityFramework
>
> StackTrace:
>   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.BeginDbTransaction(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.BeginTransaction()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass4b.<ExecuteFunction>b__49()
>      at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction(String functionName, ObjectParameter[] parameters)
>      at iTax.Models.DB_iTAXEntities1.sp_Visit_Plan_Not_Found(Nullable`1 operator, Nullable`1 invoice, Nullable`1 client) in D:\Projects\iTAX\source code\iTax\Models\Model1.Context.cs:line 564
>      at iTax.Controllers.Follow_UpController.Visit() in D:\Projects\iTAX\source code\iTax\Controllers\Follow_UpController.cs:line 290
>      at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3d()
>      at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
>
> Inner Exception 1:
>   SqlException: New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session.

C# code:

```
var form = Request.Form;
var ops = long.Parse(form["Operator"]);
var keys = form.AllKeys.Where(A=> !A.Contains("Operator")).Select(A => long.Parse(A));
var plan = M.T_Visit_Plan.Where(V => keys.Any(A => A == V.Client));

int i = 0;

foreach (var item in plan)
    M.sp_Visit_Plan_Not_Found(ops, M.T_Invoice.Where(A => A.Client == item.Client).Max(A => A.id), item.Client);

return RedirectToAction("Visit", new { Operator = ops });
```

Stored procedure code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Visit_Plan_Not_Found] 
    @Operator BIGINT = 0,
    @Invoice BIGINT = 0, 
    @Client BIGINT = 0
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO T_Visit (Operator, Invoice, Date, Mode, Client)
    VALUES (@Operator,@Invoice, GETDATE(), 5, @Client)

    DECLARE @Visit BIGINT

    SELECT @Visit = MAX(id) 
    FROM T_Visit

    UPDATE T_Visit_Plan
    SET Visit = @Visit
    WHERE (Client = @Client)
END
```

Use this code but time out command

```
public static void Visit_Plan_Not_Found(long ops, long invoice, long client)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(new EntityConnectionStringBuilder(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB_iTAXEntities1"].ConnectionString).ProviderConnectionString);
        using (con)
        {
            string query = @"INSERT INTO T_Visit
                                           (Operator, Invoice, Date, Mode, Client)
                             VALUES        (@Operator, @Invoice, GETDATE(), 5, @Client)

                             DECLARE @Visit BIGINT

                             SELECT @Visit = MAX(id) 
                             FROM T_Visit

                             UPDATE       T_Visit_Plan
                             SET                Visit = scope_identity()
                             WHERE        (Client = @Client)";

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Operator", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = ops;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Invoice", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = invoice;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Client", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = client;

                if (cmd.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed) con.Open();

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                if (cmd.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open) con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: A couple of suggestions. Instead of `SELECT @Visit = MAX(id) FROM T-Visit` , use `SET @Visit = SCOPE_IDENTITY()`. Upload the actual execution plan [here](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and add the link to your question. It may be than an index on `T_Visit_Plan.Client` isn't being used (assuming one exists).

Comment: not work and not change any thing

Comment: Where did you post the execution plan link?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
var plan = M.T_Visit_Plan.Where(V => keys.Any(A => A == V.Client));
```

creates a query, but does not run it. Then this line:

```
foreach (var item in plan)
```

Runs the query and begins retrieving the results, but does not load them all into memory.  Then this line:

```
M.sp_Visit_Plan_Not_Found . . .
```

Tries to run a stored procedure on the same connection that's being used to retrieve the results.

The fix is simple:  Load the results of the first query into a list before you iterate them:

```
var planQuery = M.T_Visit_Plan.Where(V => keys.Any(A => A == V.Client));
var plan = planQuery.ToList();
```

Comment: DONE, Thanks for helping, but i have a question abut Linq ToList(), 
if return data and not to list this query load to memory ? but some time not tolist and return data